# Is it safe to use echo to pass sensitive data into chpasswd?

Tags: bash, security, password

I am trying to mass set a few user account passwords using `chpasswd`. The passwords should be generated randomly and printed to `stdout` (I need to write them down or put them in a password store), and also passed into `chpasswd`.

Naively, I would do this like this

```
{
  echo student1:$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '')
  echo student2:$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '')
} | tee >(chpasswd)
```

However I worry about passing the new password as a commandline argument to `echo`, because arguments are usually visible to other users in `ps -aux` (although I never saw any `echo` line appear in `ps`).

Is there an alternative way of prepending a value to my returned password, and then passing it into `chpasswd`?

Comment: `echo` is a shell built-in. It would not turn up in the process table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code should be safe as `echo` won't show up in the process table since it's a shell built-in.

Here's an alternative solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=20
paste -d : <( seq -f 'student%.0f' 1 "$n" ) \
           <( tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 13 | head -n "$n" ) |
tee secret.txt | chpasswd
```

This creates your student names and passwords, `n` of them, without passing any passwords on any command line of any command.

The `paste` utility glues together several files as columns and inserts a delimiter in-between them. Here, we use `:` as the delimiter and give it two "files" (process substitutions).  The first one contains the output of a `seq` command that creates 20 student usernames, and the second contains the output of a pipeline that creates 20 random strings of length 13.

If you have a file with usernames already generated:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(wc -l <usernames.txt)

paste -d : usernames.txt \
           <( tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9' </dev/urandom | fold -w 13 | head -n "$n" ) |
tee secret.txt | chpasswd
```

These will save the passwords and usernames to the file `secret.txt` instead of showing the generated passwords in the terminal.

Comment: That's a clever solution that doesn't need `echo` or `printf`, however the code is a bit awkward to decipher

Comment: @NilsWerner Added a bit more explanation. Let me know if there's a particular thing you'd like me to expand on.

Comment: You should not rely on `echo` being a shell builtin though.  On most shells it is, but there is absolutely no requirement that itis.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That is absolutely true.  In `bash`, however, it is a built-in utility.  My suggested alternative solution also does not rely on `echo`, and could easily be rewritten to be run under any Bourne-like shell if one is ok with useng temporary files (or named pipes).

Comment: @Kusalananda Just curious, is there an effective difference between `tee secret.txt > >(chpasswd)` and `tee secret.txt | chpasswd`? The latter seems far more common, so I'm wondering why you chose to use process substitution instead of a plain pipe

Comment: @ChristopherShroba No reason other than it's similar to the code that was already in the question (using a process substitution with `tee`). Now that you've pointed it out, I think I will actually change it (it looks better). Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`echo` is very likely built in to the shell, so it would not appear in `ps` as a separate process.

But you don't need to use the command substitution, you can just have the output from the pipeline directly to `chpasswd`:

```
{  printf "%s:" "$username";
   head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo ''
} | chpasswd
```

If you want to change multiple passwords with one run of `chpasswd`, it should be easy to have the essential parts repeated. Or make it into a function:

```
genpws() {
    for user in "$@"; do
        printf "%s:" "$user";
        head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13
        echo
    done
}
genpws username1 username2... | chpasswd
```

---

As an aside: that `head /dev/urandom` feels a bit odd since `urandom` isn't line-oriented. It might read excessive amounts of bytes from it, which will affect the kernel's notion of available entropy, which in turn may lead to `/dev/random` blocking. It might be cleaner to just read a fixed amount of data, and to use something like `base64` to convert the random bytes to printable characters (instead of just tossing away about 3/4 of the bytes you get).

Something like this would give you approx. 16 characters and numbers:

```
head -c 12 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9
```

(that is, 16 less the amount of `+` and `/` characters in the output of `base64`. The chance of either is 1/32 per character, so if I got my combinatorics right, that gives about a 99 % chance of leaving at least 14 characters, and a 99.99 % chance of leaving at least 12.)

Comment: Your `printf` solution doesn't do what my original code does: return multiple lines for multiple usernames, but I appreciate your remarks on `head urandom`

Comment: @NilsWerner, well, I though the expansion to multiple users obvious. But no matter, we could make a function to produce the username:password pairs for multiple users in one go. (see edit)

Comment: You can't really rely on the first 10 "lines" from urandom containing enough of the characters that you want. Just run urandom directly through tr instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda, do you mean my `head -c 10 | base64` pipeline, or Nils's one with `head | tr`? 10 "lines" of random bytes is very likely to be hundreds of bytes (given that only 1 in 256 would be newlines), though in _theory_ it might be exactly 10 bytes, but the odds of that are completely negligible. Similarly when using `base64`, if the random bytes happen to be say just `\xff`, then the base64 will be just a string of slashes, but that's pretty unlikely too. If you care, you can read more than 10 bytes, the reduce the odds of that, and then cut the length of the resulting output.

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm referring to both codes. If you read random bytes, and want something of a particular length after filtering out what you don't want, then don't cut off the data source until you're sure that you got what you need. As you say, it's very _unlikely_ that you'd get a string of ten newlines from `/dev/urandom`, but risk is not 0%.

Comment: @Kusalananda, there's also a nonzero chance that you'll guess my password on the first try, etc. but still we go on every day trusting that the odds are so miniscule that it won't happen. Granted, I would sound more convincing if you could tell you the odds of 10 "lines" of random bytes being less than N bytes in length, for some N, but I can't remember the probability equations right now, so I can't do that.

Comment: Now, if that was actually a fast random byte generator, I wouldn't care that much about optimizing its use, but `u/random` on Linux isn't particularly fast, and there is the problem that excessive reads from even `urandom` it will cause `/dev/random` to block. (Which just probably means that everyone should link their `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom`, but I don't think that's a very common default.)

Comment: The odds of getting a newline byte when reading one byte from /dev/urandom is 1/256. So, if I'm not mistaken, the odds of getting ten newline bytes in a row would be (1/256)^10 or, according to my calculator, about 8.3e-25. The odds of getting ten alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) would be (62/256)^10 ~ 6.9e-7.

Comment: If I got my equations right, the odds of having at least 10 newlines within say 100 random bytes is about 10^-11. In other words, the chance of getting at least 100 bytes out of `head /dev/urandom` is about 0.99999999999, and that should give an average of about 24 alphanumeric characters.